# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x^2)}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there an easy way to solve this or would I have to painstakingly use l'hopitals rule many times over? $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-x}\sin(x^2)}{x^4}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ \frac{e^{-x}\sin x^2}{x^4} = \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{e^{x}} \frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}. $$
The last two factors approach $1$ as $x \to 0$. What happens with the first factor?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{e^{-x}\sin(x^2)}{x^4}=\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}\cdot \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$$

then recall that by standard limit $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taylor formulae.

For instance, $e^{-x}\sin(x^2)=(1+O(x))(x^2+O(x^4)) = x^2+O(x^3)$ and so, the limit does not exits.

Answer (score 0):

Just break the limit down.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-x}\sin (x^2)}{x^4} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (x^2)}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{e^x} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Now, evaluate the limits as $x \to 0$.